# The number of digits of an integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Classic problem, but in Haskell this time. I try to do this the C way but I keep getting this error

```
Variable not in scope: numDigits :: Integer -> t
```

Here is the code I wrote

```
numDigits :: Integer -> Integer
numDigits n = toInteger (round (logBase 10 (fromIntegral n)) + 1)
```

Did i do something wrong? Or log

Comment: What's the signature of `toInteger`? Can't remember. Also, why not just define it as `length. show`?

Comment: toInteger because log Base 10 return a Double I suppose ?

Comment: Are you doing this in a REPL, or a source file?

Comment: I use emacs and Terminal cause I have a Mac

Comment: But are you trying to write this code in GHCI in the terminal?

Comment: And does it actually say `Integer -> t`,  or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes I wrote it in GHCI and no it is not a typo. I copied it straight from the terminal

Comment: This is likely a GHCI issue. Certain versions of GHCI execute every line 1 at a time. When it evals the signature line, it can't find a matching definition, so it throws. I think you surround the code in curly braces or something to have it eval everything at once.

Comment: You realise you can't just paste Haskell definitions in the GHCi REPL, right? You'd need to write `let numDigits :: Integer -> Integer; numDigits n = toInteger (round (logBase 10 (fromIntegral n)) + 1)`.

Comment: I wrote it in emacs and compile using ghci in my terminal, so I didn't use let

Comment: @K.U I think he's right, iirc, let is the workaround. Your code works: http://rextester.com/AHGX41414

Comment: I don't think let is the problem here cause I wrote it in emacs and complied in terminal. My other code worked just fine this way though

Comment: No problems when entered directly into WinGHCi.

Comment: If you are using a sufficiently recent GHC, an alternative to putting everything in a single line is entering `:{` (on its own in a line), then pasting your code without changes (no need to add `let` or remove linebreaks) and finally entering `:}` (also in a separate line). GHCi can handle most things without changes in this way.

Comment: How are you calling `numDigits`?  That error is from a call site, not the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI I voted to close because you have either made a typo or failed to provide us with the actual failing code.  The code in question is valid, but you should specify how you're loading it and how you're calling it.

For demonstration:

```
% cat so.hs
numDigits :: Integer -> Integer
numDigits n = toInteger (round (logBase 10 (fromIntegral n)) + 1)
% ghci so.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/tommd/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> numDigits 1948
4
```

Comment: Buggy with `9999` as input on my machine

Comment: Sure, the algorithms is shoddy but the question was about loading and testing code in a repl.